# Plotting 3D region depending on 2 parameters with constraints

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, constraint

I'm trying to plot the full range that a set of estimates gives. They depend on some parameters and conditions, but I haven't been able to to it effectively with RegionPlot3D. Here is the set that I would like to plot:

````
$$\textbf{Parameters}:\quad \theta,\alpha,\beta,\gamma.$$
$$\textbf{Conditions on parameters}:\quad 0<\theta<1,\quad 1\leq \beta \leq \infty.$$
$$\textbf{More constraints:}\quad \begin{cases}
4\theta+\frac{2}{\beta}\theta<1,\\
6\theta-\frac{2}{\beta}\theta<1.\\
\end{cases} $$

$$\textbf{Region to be plotted}:\left(\frac{1}{1-2\theta-\frac{\theta}{\beta}},\frac{1}{1-2\theta-\frac{\theta(\beta-1)}{\beta}},\frac{1}{3\theta}\right) $$```

I first tried this:

``ParametricPlot3D[{1/(1 - 2*\[Theta] - \[Theta]/\[Beta]), 1/(
  1 - 2*\[Theta] - (\[Theta]*(\[Beta] - 1))/\[Beta]), 1/(
  3*\[Theta])}, {\[Theta], 0, 1}, {\[Beta], 1, \[Infinity]}]``

But it doesn't run. I didn't figure how to implement the constraints... any input would be very welcome :)
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\textbf{Parameters}:\quad \theta,\alpha,\beta,\gamma.$$
$$\textbf{Conditions on parameters}:\quad 0<\theta<1,\quad 1\leq \beta \leq \infty.$$
$$\textbf{More constraints:}\quad \begin{cases}
4\theta+\frac{2}{\beta}\theta<1,\\
6\theta-\frac{2}{\beta}\theta<1.\\
\end{cases} $$

$$\textbf{Region to be plotted}:\left(\frac{1}{1-2\theta-\frac{\theta}{\beta}},\frac{1}{1-2\theta-\frac{\theta(\beta-1)}{\beta}},\frac{1}{3\theta}\right) $$

Use `RegionFunction` and replace `∞` to `5` or other finite number.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{1/(1 - 2*θ - θ/β), 
  1/(1 - 2*θ - (θ*(β - 1))/β), 
  1/(3*θ)}, {θ, 0, 1}, {β, 1, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{θ, β}, 
   4 θ + 2/β < 1 && 6 θ - 2/β < 1]]
```